# Java.io.IOException: wrong number of values (WEKA CSV to ARFF)

Tags: csv, exception, weka

Currently working on a Data Mining project using my own dataset I had found using Weka. The only issue is that taking my file from csv format and converting it into arff format is causing issues.

```
java.io.IOException: wrong number of values. Read 2, expected 5, Read Token[EOL], line 3
```

This is the error I am getting. I have browsed around online looking for similar issues and have tried removing all quotes and special characters that throw this exception. Every place I looked told me to remove special characters and I believe there are none left. The link to my dataset is here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xqEe7MZE9SdKB_yvFSgWeSVYuDrq0b31Eu5oECNbGH0/edit#gid=1736568367&vpid=A1

This is the first three lines of my file where the first is the attribute names, file is separated by commas in note

Inequality Adjusted HPI Rank,Sub Region,Inequality Adjusted Life Expectancy,Inquality Adjusted Well being,Footprint
,Inequality adjusted HPI

1,1,73.1,6.9,2.5,48.2

2,6,65.17333333,5.487667631,1.390974448,45.97489063

Comment: Please include a snapshot of the relevant information in your spreadsheet in your question. Links can go bad over time and would then be unhelpful for future searchers experiencing your particular problem in their own code.

Answer (score 1):

If you open your file with a text editor, you will see that Footprint has quotes around it. Delete the quotes and you are good to go!

Weka is normally not that good in reading CSV files that include special characters, and ARFF files are normally easier to use. Therefore, in such cases, the easiest way is to convert your CSV file to an ARFF file using R ("RWeka" and "foreign" libraries can handle this conversion).

Comment: when i did that it still was throwing the same error, manually typed out the names of the attributes and copied the values underneath it and it worked fine. Not sure why it wasn't working that way haha

Answer (score 0):

There is also another possibility. I was creating my CSV file and the header had a different number of elements compared to the rest of the data. So, check the header as well...!